# Limit number of HTTP connections from a single source in IIS7?

Tags: iis-7

Is there a way in IIS7 to limit the number of HTTP connections allowed from a single source?  We occasionaly get mild denial of service attacks that we could prevent with some limitations on the number of connections allowed from any single IP.  I understand this could impact some legitimate requests, but we'd set the threshold fairly high.

Comment: I would ask this question on serverfault.

Comment: serverfault is still in beta.. :(

Answer (score 9):

Ah!  I think I found it.  This http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2009/02/16/dynamic-ip-restrictions-for-iis-7-0-beta.aspx is what I'm looking for.

Thanks all.

Mark

Answer (score 2):

Here is the latest home of the extension: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/dynamic-ip-restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Under properties for the website in IIS click on Performance and select the number of connections limited to.

Comment: But wouldn't this limit connections for the server overall?  What I really want is to say "When X number of concurrent connections originate from the same IP, limit that number of connections to X" or something along those lines.